# RubyMotion Rake failed - New App

Tags: ruby, xcode, rubymotion

ran these commands:

`create HelloWorld`

`cd HelloWorld`

`rake`

Error:

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

`================================================================================
The application terminated. A crash report file may have been generated by the
system, use`rake crashlog' to open it. Use `rake debug=1' to restart the app
in the debugger.
================================================================================`

`rake aborted!`

`TypeError: no implicit conversion from nil to integer
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/template/ios.rb:243:in`exit'
/Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/template/ios.rb:243:in `block in <top (required)>'`

Comment: Can you mention what version of Ruby you are running? (Run `ruby -v`)

Comment: Did you make sure to have up tp date rubymotion and used bundle to update your gems?